# How do you break up content from an include .txt file?

Tags: php, explode

How do you break up content from an include .txt file in PHP? I know how to do it with a .php include file by creating arrays and using the explode function. But with a text file, I cannot use arrays. I'm trying to get my page to show this:

```
John Lee
University of Oregon
Sophmore

Anna Smith
Harvard
Senior

Thomas Stout
University of California Irvine
Junior
```

Here is my code:

.txt file:

```
John Lee~University of Oregon~Sophmore
Anna Smith~Harvard~Senior
Thomas Stout~University of California Irvine~Junior
```

student.php file:

```
<?php
include ("student.php)";
#???
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the `.txt` file into a variable and then run `preg_split()` with an appropriate Regex? In you case you want to split at the ~ character and at line breaks, so it would be like so:

```
$input = file_get_contents('students.txt');
$output = preg_split( "/(~|\n)/", $input );
```

Then it's as easy as:

```
foreach( $output as $line )
    echo $line . '<br/>';
```

<kbd>[**Example**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/98a-bhp)</kbd>